# (php) change a duration to something useable by my calendar

Tags: php, date, duration

I have a series of event dates (variable durations) in the following formats:

- 28 April 2020
- 3 - 5 May 2020
- 3 May - 5 June 2020
- 20 Dec 2020 - 15 Jan 2021

I want to keep these this way, for readability.

But my calendar needs a standard way of reading these so it can output these events:

- 28 April 2020 should become 28 April 2020 - 28 April 2020
- 3 - 5 May 2020 should become 3 May 2020 - 5 May 2020
- 3 May - 5 June 2020 should become 3 May 2020 - 5 June 2020
- 20 Dec 2020 - 15 Jan 2021 ==> this the calendar can handle.

Any thoughts on how to do this in php?

Comment: until I write the answer for you, please read this : https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really recommend storing your dates as two separate values (start/end) and then formatting on output rather than trying to decode the formatted output.

If you are stuck with this approach, you can use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match) to match your different formats and then extract the start and end dates from the matched values:

```
$dates = array(
    '28 April 2020',
    '3 - 5 May 2020',
    '3 May - 5 June 2020',
    '20 Dec 2020 - 15 Jan 2021'
    );

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    preg_match('/^(\d+)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)(?:\s-\s(\d+)\s(\w+)\s(\d+))?|(\d+)\s(\w+)\s-\s(\d+)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)|(\d+)\s-\s(\d+)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)$/', $date, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[12])) {
        // dd - dd mmm yyyy format
        $start_date = "${matches[12]} ${matches[14]} ${matches[15]}";
        $end_date   = "${matches[13]} ${matches[14]} ${matches[15]}";
    }
    elseif (isset($matches[7])) {
        // dd mmm - dd mmm yyyy format
        $start_date = "${matches[7]} ${matches[8]} ${matches[11]}";
        $end_date   = "${matches[9]} ${matches[10]} ${matches[11]}";
    }
    elseif (isset($matches[4])) {
        // dd mmm yyyy - dd mmm yyyy format
        $start_date = "${matches[1]} ${matches[2]} ${matches[3]}";
        $end_date   = "${matches[4]} ${matches[5]} ${matches[6]}";
    }
    elseif (isset($matches[1])) {
        // dd mmm yyyy format
        $start_date = "${matches[1]} ${matches[2]} ${matches[3]}";
        $end_date   = "${matches[1]} ${matches[2]} ${matches[3]}";
    }
    else {
        // no match
        $start_date = '???';
        $end_date = '???';
    }
    echo "$start_date - $end_date\n";
}
```

Output:

```
28 April 2020 - 28 April 2020
3 May 2020 - 5 May 2020
3 May 2020 - 5 June 2020
20 Dec 2020 - 15 Jan 2021
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5ZCFQ)

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
$inputDateString = "28 April 2020";
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat("j F Y",$inputDateString); 
echo $dateObject->format('d m Y') . " - " . $inputDateString->format('d m Y');

$inputDateString1 = "3 May";
$dateObject1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("j F",$inputDateString1); 

$inputDateString2 = "5 May 2020";
$dateObject2 = DateTime::createFromFormat("j F Y",$inputDateString2);
echo $dateObject1->format('d m ').date('Y'); . " - ". $dateObject2->format('d m Y');
```

calculate the interval

```
$interval = $dateObject2->diff($dateObject1);
echo $interval->format('%d days');
```